# netbeans and oracle sql developer list different results

Tags: oracle, netbeans, weblogic

Hi I am using weblogic server. Running with netbeans gives different results, running with oracle sql developer gives different results. What could be the problem?

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   (SELECT(SELECT Count(*) AS sayfasayisi 
               FROM   indirim_liste lst 
               WHERE  lst.kategori IS NOT NULL 
                      AND lst.indirimtarih IS NOT NULL 
                      AND lst.indirimyuzde > 5 
                      AND lst.aktif = 1 
                      AND lst.edittarih > sysdate - 1) 
              AS 
                     sayfasayisi, 
              Row_number() 
                OVER ( 
                  ORDER BY To_date(indirimtarih, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC) 
              rn, 
              lst.hbkod, 
              lst.isim, 
              lst.fiyat, 
              lst.indirimyuzde, 
              lst.kategori, 
              lst.firma, 
              To_char(lst.indirimtarih, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') 
              AS 
                     indirimtarih 
        FROM   indirim_liste lst 
        WHERE  lst.kategori IS NOT NULL 
               AND lst.indirimtarih IS NOT NULL 
               AND lst.indirimyuzde > 5 
               AND lst.aktif = 1 
               AND lst.edittarih > sysdate - 1 
        ORDER  BY To_date(indirimtarih, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC) t 
WHERE  t.rn BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the time of execution, and the contents of lst.edittarih, the sysdate-1 can result in different counts and rows selected as time changes.  Especially if that field has a time component stored in it.